# Trying to show dates within 30 days of another date

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to show all dates within a 30 day period after another date, but I can't get the last line correct. The result should show all cases of GARN_DATE that are within a 30 day period after TRANS_DATE with a certain code and all cases of SERVICE_DATE after TRANS_DATE with the same code.

This is what I have so far:

```
    WHERE (CODE LIKE 'XPSREJ'
    AND TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2021-11-26' AND '2022-05-256') 
    AND TRANS_DATE < (DATEADD (day, 30, GARN_DATE) )
    AND TRANS_DATE < SERVICE_DATE
```

Comment: So why isn't what you have working? Are you getting a syntax error? Unexpected results? Something else?

Comment: `TRANS_DATE BETWEEN '2021-11-26' AND '2022-05-256'` is going to error; there aren't 256 days in February. Though it's generally recommended to not use `BETWEEN` with dates; many think it works differently to how it does. Stick to `>=` and `<` logic.

Comment: Sounds like you need `AND TRANS_DATE > DATEADD (day, -30, GARN_DATE)`